# SVG icons on website are turning transparent

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using GeneratePress and GenerateBlocks to make a website on WordPress.

I have four blocks of text that I would like to have an SVG icon above.
I have bought these icons from iStock, three as part of a pack, and the Australia icon separate.
GenerateBlocks has a handy SVG icon picker, where you just paste the SVG html into the box and it will appear in the correct place.

The issue I am having is when I add a fourth SVG icon. When I do this, the rest of them become transparent, which is not what I want.
[(Without fourth icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yrSy.png) [(With fourth icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyBIe.png)

Below is the code for the fourth SVG icon, which I am putting in the left-most slot:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24.88 25.7">
<defs>
<style>
.cls-1,.cls-2,.cls-3,.cls-4{
  fill:none;stroke:#3b383f;stroke-linejoin:round;
}
.cls-1,.cls-3{
  stroke-linecap:square;
}
.cls-1,.cls-2{
  opacity:0.1;
}
</style>
</defs>
<g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><polyline class="cls-1" points="19.78 22.65 19.78 25.2 1.2 25.2 1.2 1.2 15.83 1.2 19.78 5.25 19.78 9.51"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="15.83 1.2 15.83 5.15 19.78 5.15"/><path class="cls-2" d="M11.6,17.49a5.62,5.62,0,1,1,7.88,1.07A5.63,5.63,0,0,1,11.6,17.49Z"/><line class="cls-2" x1="20.15" y1="20.09" x2="19.18" y2="18.81"/><path class="cls-2" d="M19.19,21.17l2.26-1.72,1,1.38,1.6,2.09a1.43,1.43,0,0,1-.27,2h0a1.43,1.43,0,0,1-2-.27l-.91-1.2Z"/><line class="cls-1" x1="13.24" y1="16.24" x2="14.58" y2="16.24"/><line class="cls-1" x1="13.2" y1="11.93" x2="14.47" y2="11.93"/><line class="cls-1" x1="12.5" y1="14.09" x2="15.21" y2="14.09"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="6.87" x2="3.87" y2="21.3"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="7.61" x2="6.37" y2="7.61"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="11.93" x2="8.77" y2="11.93"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="9.77" x2="7.6" y2="9.77"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="16.24" x2="8.56" y2="16.24"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="14.09" x2="8.07" y2="14.09"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="18.4" x2="9.71" y2="18.4"/><line class="cls-1" x1="3.87" y1="20.56" x2="7.31" y2="20.56"/><polyline class="cls-3" points="19.08 21.95 19.08 24.5 0.5 24.5 0.5 0.5 15.13 0.5 19.08 4.55 19.08 8.81"/><polyline class="cls-4" points="15.13 0.5 15.13 4.45 19.08 4.45"/><path class="cls-4" d="M10.9,16.79a5.62,5.62,0,1,1,7.88,1.07A5.63,5.63,0,0,1,10.9,16.79Z"/><line class="cls-4" x1="19.45" y1="19.39" x2="18.48" y2="18.11"/><path class="cls-4" d="M18.49,20.47l2.26-1.72,1,1.38,1.6,2.09a1.43,1.43,0,0,1-.27,2h0a1.43,1.43,0,0,1-2-.27l-.91-1.2Z"/><line class="cls-3" x1="12.54" y1="15.54" x2="13.88" y2="15.54"/><line class="cls-3" x1="12.5" y1="11.23" x2="13.77" y2="11.23"/><line class="cls-3" x1="11.8" y1="13.39" x2="14.51" y2="13.39"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="6.17" x2="3.17" y2="20.6"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="6.91" x2="5.67" y2="6.91"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="11.23" x2="8.07" y2="11.23"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="9.07" x2="6.9" y2="9.07"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="15.54" x2="7.86" y2="15.54"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="13.39" x2="7.37" y2="13.39"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="17.7" x2="9.01" y2="17.7"/><line class="cls-3" x1="3.17" y1="19.86" x2="6.61" y2="19.86"/></g></g></svg>
```

Any feedback would be really appreciated, this has been plaguing me for a while.

Cheers

Comment: Please provide a codepen, Snippet, or live link.  This is not enough to understand the issue

Comment: Presumably these icons don't have distinct id values or classes so when you put more than one on a page they conflict.

Comment: Because ``<style>`` definitions are global; ``opacity:0.1`` will be applied to all elements ``cls-1`` and ``cls-2`` in your page. Maybe the easiest fix is to "restore" everything with an extra ``<style>`` tag with higher Specificity.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That was spot on, if you wanted to add it as an answer so I could accept it that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because  definitions are global;

**opacity:0.1 will be applied to all elements `with classes `cls-1` and `cls-2` in your page.**

- Maybe the easiest fix is to "restore" everything with an extra `<style>` tag with higher Specificity.
- Otherwise you have to change the SVG to work with unique classes
- Or put your SVG in a shadowRoot so all SVG CSS becomes "local" and does not leak out to global DOM. See the [`<load-file>` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) for an example